# Select into view a slide master page with PowerPoint Interop

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

Is it possible in PowerPoint Interop used from C# to programatically select a slide master page into view, just like you would select a regular slide? Either by giving the ID of that master page or from the slide that has it as template.

I managed to switch the view to the slide master:

```
_pptApplication.ActiveWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewMasterThumbnails;
```

I tried selecting a slide first and then switching to the master view, but this instruction always places into view the first slide master page, not the one associated to the selected slide.

Likewise, I'd like to know if this is possible for notes, handouts and their masters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the method .Select() on a CustomLayout object in addition to setting .ViewType as you had already figured out.

Here are two examples:

```
using NetOffice.OfficeApi.Enums;
using NetOffice.PowerPointApi.Enums;
using System;
using PowerPoint = NetOffice.PowerPointApi;

namespace ExportSlides
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var app = PowerPoint.Application.GetActiveInstance())
            {
                SelectSlideMasterLayoutOfActiveSlide(app);
                ActiveSlideMasterLayoutByIndex(app.ActivePresentation, 4);
            }
        }

        private static void ActiveSlideMasterLayoutByIndex(PowerPoint.Presentation activePresentation, int customLayoutIndex)
        {
            activePresentation.Windows[1].ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewSlideMaster; //PpViewType.ppViewMasterThumbnails doesn't work for me for some reason
            activePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[customLayoutIndex].Select();
        }

        private static void SelectSlideMasterLayoutOfActiveSlide(PowerPoint.Application app)
        {
            var activeWindow = app.ActiveWindow;

            var slideObj = activeWindow.View.Slide;

            if (slideObj.GetType() == typeof(PowerPoint.Slide))
            {
                var slide = (PowerPoint.Slide)slideObj;

                activeWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewSlideMaster; //PpViewType.ppViewMasterThumbnails doesn't work for me for some reason

                slide.CustomLayout.Select();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea `CustomLayout` was the key to this. One remark, though: when I tried this it didn't work when comparing `slideObj.GetType() == typeof(PowerPoint.Slide)`, instead I had to cast `activeWindow.View.Slide` to `Slide` and then it worked.

Comment: One more question: I noticed that, when selecting by index, you can't select the very first slide master page. Is there a similar way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you get there automatically if you select ViewType, if I recall correctly, so try just setting the value to something else and back... does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works this way. I was trying to avoid messing with the ViewType, because it has an undesired side effect: it steals the focus from whatever window you have active and sets it to the PowerPoint application.

Comment: I can't seem to find another way. Perhaps you can make the current active window always on top, then set ViewType, then make it no longer be always on top again?